# Stripping texts in a variable : javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, strip

Consider variable like

```
var url='http://www.example.com/index.php?id=ss';
```

or

```
var url='http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/index.php';
```

In these variables, i want to get only the domain part i.e `http://www.example.com`, stripping out other texts. Is this possible in ordinary javascript or jquery ?

Please help

Comment: I mis-read your question and gave you an incorrect answer, so I updated my solution. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative using substrings and indexOf's :)

```
/* FUNCTION: getBaseUrl
 * DESCRIPTION: Strips a url's sub folders and returns it
 * EXAMPLE: getBaseUrl( http://stackoverflow.com/questions
 *   /3102830/stripping-texts-in-a-variable-javascript );
 * returns -- http://stackoverflow.com/
 */
function getBaseUrl( url ) {
    if ( url.indexOf('.') == -1 || url.indexOf('/') == -1 ) { return false; }

    var result = url.substr(0, url.indexOf( '/' , url.indexOf('.') ) + 1 );
    return( result );
}
```

Comment: This requires the domain name have a `.` in it. Would fail for eg. `http://localhost/`, `http://to/` or those integer-IP-address hacks, or IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 4):

No need to wrangle URL strings. The browser has its own URL parser which you can get access to using the `location`-like properties of an `HTMLAnchorElement`:

```
var a= document.createElement('a');
a.href= 'http://www.example.com/index.php?id=ss';

alert(a.protocol); // http
alert(a.hostname); // www.example.com
alert(a.pathname); // /index.php
alert(a.search);   // ?id=ss
// also port, hash
```

Comment: +1 for a clever hack, although strictly speaking, it's not javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this explicitly with URIs then you can use a js URI library for this. A sample library like [js-uri](http://code.google.com/p/js-uri/)

```
var url=new URI('http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/index.php');
var sch = uri.scheme // http
var auth = uri.authority // www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url='http://www.example.com/index.php?id=ss';
url = url.replace(/^.*?:\/\/(.*?)\/.*$/, "$1");

alert(url);
```